# Minimum size of set

Tags: combinatorics

Consider a set $S$ of $k$ elements $(1,2,\ldots,k)$. Let $A$ and $B$ denotes two subsets of $S$ . We want to find minimum value of $k$ such that for each pair of $A$ and $B$, size$(A-B)\geq 1$ and size$(B-A)\geq 1$.
**Note:**Number of subsets will be $n$. Can we find the minimum $k$??

Example:

- for $n=1$, $k=1$, $(s=\{1\})$
- for $n=3$, $k=3$ since subsets are $\{1,2\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\}$.
- for $n=5$, $k=4$ since we require $4$ elements at least and subsets are $\{1,2\},\{3,4\},\{1,3\},\{2,3\},\{2,4\}$

or **find minimum $k$ such that each pair out of $n$ subsets have at least one element different.**

Comment: You start by saying A is of size $m$, but later you only use $n$ and for the number of subsets instead of their size.  Please clarify.  Are your subsets always of size $2$ like your examples?

Comment: sorry for that, subsets can be of any size but less than or equal to k and greater than or equal to 1.

Comment: both pair of sets should have atleast one element different in each but {2} does not have any elemnet different in {1,2}

Comment: I realized that right after I submitted my comment haha—hence the deletion of it. (Oops.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Certainly if all the subsets are the same size, you will have $|A - B | \ge 1$ and $|B-A| \ge 1$.  You get the most subsets if they are half the size of the universe.  If $k$ is even, there are ${k \choose k/2}=\frac{ k!}{(k/2)!^2}$ subsets of size $k/2$, so we need $\frac{ k!}{(k/2)!^2}\approx \frac {4^{k/2}}{\sqrt{k\pi/2}}\ge n$  You can find the minimum $k$ by trial-I don't know of an algebraic solution.

For odd $k$, let $k=2m+1$.  Then there are $\frac {k!}{m!(m+1)!}$ subsets of size $m$ (or $m+1$) so we need $\frac {k!}{m!(m+1)!} \ge n$

We get the following limits:  $$\begin {array} {r| r| r} k&\text{subset size} &n\\ \hline 2&1&2\\3&1&3\\4&2&6\\5&2&10\\6&3&20\\7&3&35\\8&4&70\\9&4&126\\10&5&252\\11&5&462\\12&6&924\\13&6&1716\\14&7&3432\\15&7&6435\\16&8&12870\\ \end {array}$$  Round $n$ up to the next entry and read $k$

Comment: this is not right for example for n=4 we need atleast 4 elements but your formula gives 3.

Comment: It gets harder when $k$ is odd-I just did the even case.  I'll add in the odd case.  For $n=6$ we can add $\{1,4\}$ to your solution for $n=5$

Comment: yes for n=6 we can add {1,4}

Comment: can you kindly explain for random n how to read k??

Comment: @savvisingh:  just find the next value for $n$ that is above the one you want.  So if you wanted $n=153$, you would see that being greater than $126$, less than or equal to $252$ and pick $k=10$ and use subsets of size $5$

Comment: ok i got it, so first i need to calculate the limits for k and see the upper bounds on n.Then i do as you suggested

Comment: thank you @Ross for this explanation:)thank you very much